# Access User ICollection from SQL database in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my `Models` folder, I have an `ICollection` of type `Item`.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    [Column]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    [Column]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    [Column]
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

That `Item` class is right here:

```
public class Item : ApplicationUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
}
```

When I updated my database, I got this:

[image]

I got a table for the `User`, and the user's `ICollection<Item>`.

Now my problem for this is how do I go about in accessing or manipulating this piece of data in razor pages. So far I have this for my razor page and for the backend side of it.

```
<form method="post">

<div>Item Name</div>
<input asp-for="Input.ItemName" />

<div>Item Description</div>
<input asp-for="Input.ItemDescription" />

<button type="submit">Save</button>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ArrayCheckNetCore.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ArrayCheckNetCore.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage
{
    public class PersonalDataModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<Item> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<PersonalDataModel> _logger;

        public PersonalDataModel(
            UserManager<Item> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, 
            ILogger<PersonalDataModel> logger)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            public string ItemName { get; set; }
            public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
        }

        private async Task LoadAsync(Item user)
        {
            var itemsname = user.ItemName;
            var itemsdescription = user.ItemDescription; 

            Input = new InputModel
            {
                ItemName = itemsname, 
                ItemDescription = itemsdescription 
            };
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
            }

            //await LoadAsync(user);
            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //await LoadAsync(user);
                return Page();
            }

            user.ItemName = Input.ItemName;
            user.ItemDescription = Input.ItemDescription; 

            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            //await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user); 
            return RedirectToPage();
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone knows how I can access these properties, thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by `User ICollection` or `User's ICollection`? Why does it matter razor page? Can you do something similar in controller/page code? I completely do not have a clue on what your problem is.

Comment: By using your model, since the Item inherit from the ApplicationUser table, after migration, it will generate one AspNetUser which contains all of the properties, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEUZl.png), might be you have other configurations. After removing the inherit from the Item model, it will generate the Items table. After that, do you mean you want to access ApplicationUser's FirstName and LastName properties when manage the Item? If that is the case, you can access the Item based on the [navigate property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Entity Framework Core with this application so, you will have to load the collection of Items either by accessing the ApplicationUser table in the DbContext or with UserManager class. Either way you use the Include() extension method with the IQueryable of Users to load the related data. Easier to show an example

```cs
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Inject DbContext
        /// </summary>
        readonly ApplicationDbContext Context;

        /// <summary>
        /// Inject UserManager
        /// </summary>
        readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager;

        public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> UsersWithItemsOption1 { get; set; } = new List<ApplicationUser>();

        public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> UsersWithItemsOption2 { get; set; } = new List<ApplicationUser>();

        public IndexModel(
            ApplicationDbContext Context,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager)
        {
            this.Context = Context;
            this.UserManager = UserManager;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            /// Option 1 - Using UserManager
            UsersWithItemsOption1 = await UserManager
                .Users
                .Include(a => a.Items)
                .ToListAsync();

            /// Option 2 -User DbContext
            UsersWithItemsOption2 = await Context
                .Users
                .Include(a => a.Items)
                .ToListAsync();


            return Page();
        }
    }
```

```
@page "/"
@model IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Items</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var user in Model.UsersWithItemsOption1)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@user.FirstName</td>
            <td>@user.LastName</td>
            <td>@user.PhoneNumber</td>
            <td>
                @if (user.Items != null)
                {
                    ///Prints out all the Item Names in a single string seperated by a comma
                    string.Join(", ", user.Items.Select(a => a.ItemName).ToList());
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a link to the documentation [Relationships - EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

Edited to update IndexModel and include html for razor page

Comment: How will I access those properties onto the frontend(Razor Pages)?

Comment: How can I add data to this? Something like in a form?

Comment: You would need a form page that would handle the updating for this model. Typically, the table page would have buttons or links that take you to the page where you can modify a single model then submit it to the database. [Introduction to Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#write-a-basic-form) this should help you with that portion

Comment: While the documentation does show how to add and submit to a form, it doesn't really go over how to submit to an ICollection type form. I've tried everything that I could think of and nothing.

Comment: I also can't seem to access the ItemName and the ItemDescription properties that are inside the Item table. If anyone knows how to access those attributes thank you.